# How to get value of stdClass object returned from twitter API?

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am using twitter API to to get application rate limit. When I made a request I get the following response (using `print_r`);

```
stdClass Object
(
[rate_limit_context] => stdClass Object
    (
        [application] => Vu62t75UIKwKA392lipsQPB91
    )

[resources] => stdClass Object
    (
        [search] => stdClass Object
            (
                [/search/tweets] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [limit] => 450
                        [remaining] => 450
                        [reset] => 1475485694
                    )

            )

    )

[httpstatus] => 200
[rate] => stdClass Object
    (
        [limit] => 180
        [remaining] => 176
        [reset] => 1475485014
    )

)
```

I am able to get values on every key as

```
$apiStatus= $limitJsonResponse->httpstatus;
$apiRateLimit=$limitJsonResponse->rate->limit;
```

But I am not able to find a way to access values of this property `[/search/tweets]`.

If I try get value of this property as other

```
$limit =$limitJsonResponse->resources->search->/search/tweets->remaining;
```

I get this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

Comment: You can use it as : `$limit =$limitJsonResponse->{'resources'}->{'search'}->{'/search/tweets'}->{'remaining'};`

Comment: Showing error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING) `

Comment: Actually getting these 2 error. (above error was due to some other mistake I made)
`Undefined property: stdClass::$/search/tw‌​eets`
`Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is a good answer but it solved my problem
I devided `stdClass` in object and expand trough the last one.

```
    $param=array('resources'=>'search');
    $limitJsonResponse=$apiObj->application_rateLimitStatus($param,true);

    // an stdClass object
    $searchObj=$limitJsonResponse->resources->search;

    $searchArray = (array)$searchObj;
    $searchTweetObj =$searchArray['/search/tweets'];
    $limit= $searchTweetObj->limit;
    echo $limit;
```